# keras module not found (No module named 'keras')

Tags: python, keras

I tried to import keras to my ANN model but I found this Module not found the type of error. I tried tp import from tensorflow.keras but still it's the same problem. [image]

No module named 'keras'

Comment: Have you installed it on your system? e.g. `pip install keras`

Comment: Yes i have installed to my machine

Comment: Try `from keras.model import Sequential`? (instead of `models`)

Comment: @Purushoth I'm pretty sure the notebook and your machine run separately

Comment: @CollinHeist will try that :)

Comment: ```pip install keras```

Answer (score 3):

Try importing `keras` first. Try:

```py
from numpy import loadtxt
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

If this doesn't work, try using TensorFlow: `pip install tensorflow` and:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
```

Comment: @Purushoth Glad I could help :)

Comment: Actually the module is called models, NOT model, this will generate an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.model'

Answer (score 1):

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

Answer (score 0):

`!pip install keras` on jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the environment. Your TensorFlow module may be installed in a different env. and Keras is in a different env. So, try to uninstall the Keras module and reinstall it.

```
$ pip uninstall keras
$ pip install keras
```

If this doesn't work, try using TensorFlow: pip install `tensorflow` and:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
```